# What is a good read about Manning condensation?

Tags: electrostatics, resource-recommendations, condensation

I was assign in a course to give half an hour talk about [Manning condensation](http://www.google.com/search?q=manning+condensation). I read Wikipedia article about it as a starter, but it's only two paragraphs long and only point to the original paper with to papers which show some deviation. I want to read about this in a textbook, any recommendations?

Comment: Hi Yotam: Book recommendations question are off-topic. If you (or somebody else?) can edit it to ask a concrete physics question, I would be happy to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

You may have some better luck looking up the phenomenon as counterion condensation. I work in this area, and I have never heard it called Manning condensation (though that is an acceptable name). The original paper ([doi](http://link.aip.org/link/doi/10.1063/1.1672157)) is where I learned how counterion condensation works; it contains a derivation of the relevant integrals, and shows how they diverge under certain circumstances. Unfortunately for those unaffiliated with a university, Manning's paper is behind a paywall.

Counterion condensation should be included in any textbook that discusses polyelectrolyte theory, but I've had trouble locating a polymer textbook that gives more than a cursory discussion of polyelectrolytes. To find any real discussion of polyelectrolytes, I had to go to biophysics, to Michel Daune's [Molecular Biophysics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198577826). Part IV is titled "Biopolymers as polyelectrolytes." It gives an overview of Manning's counterion condensation model, and compares it to the [Poisson-Boltzmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Boltzmann_equation) and [Debye-Hueckl] models. It also contains lots of citations to further reading.

Comment: Thanks. I have the article (I'm a Ph.D. student and our university is not that backward). I know this is a polyelectrolyte related stuff, but I don't know what are good reading in this field.

Answer (score 0):

A very nice and relatively detailed study of counterion condensation on a charged cylinder (at zero salt concentration) is done in this [excellent thesis](http://physics2.fau.edu/~alau/thesis.pdf) that anybody involved in the field of statistical mechanics of charged system should read in my opinion. The Manning condensation is rapidly explained page 25 and then a more elaborate calculation is done using the Poisson-Boltzmann theory (leading essentially to the same physical result).